# Suddenly can't ping default gateway (and outside internet) on Win10

Tags: networking, router

I have some Windows 10 workstations. Because of sharing, they have all set static IP.
One of them is used as "server". Basicaly nobody works on it, there are just shared files. Only about once a week, there is a user on this workstation.

Now I discovered, that sometimes, this workstation loses connection to the internet. All connections in LAN works fine, so if it happens, usually nobody notices it, so I don't know how often is this happening. But I can't ping the default gateway (192.168.5.1) and everything behind it, only LAN.
I first thought that it's just a switch going crazy, so I changed all switches in my network, but the problem persists. The only thing I didn't changed is the default gateway, TL-WR1043ND router. And I don't have any spare that I could put instead of it.

The problem usually starts out of nothing, persists few hours, and second day it's magically gone. I tried restarting all network devices, including the computer, changing it's IP, making it dynamic instead of static, removing NIC from system, reinstalling it's drivers, nothing. The router sees the PC and it's traffic, it shows there are some packets, but they got lost somewhere. Propably because something is wrong with the OS. I installed WireShark, but it started working again before I located any more detailed info.

Do you have any clue what is going on here? What should I look for if this happens again? The biggest problem is that it happens about once a month (as far as I know) and I'm not always there to do some stuff. And if I am, I try to reset everythin as described before, which doesn't help, and then I just wait for the next day, when it magically starts working.

Comment: Does anything stand out in event viewer? Also check you only have a single default gateway configured. In a command prompt type "route print" to see a list of active routes. The 0.0.0.0 is the default gateway and you should only see one entry. I have seen before where two were assigned and it worked and would intermittently loose internet then come back. If you do have two I can provide a solution.

Comment: Consider writing a batch script to ping the gateway and log the results. Run the script from the affected workstation and another one on the same subnet (preferably the same switch as the "server"). Compare the results when the problem occurs. If both machines report a problem, the gateway or intervening network equipment is at fault. If only one device reports a problem, that device or anything unique in its path to the router is at fault.